# Django dynamic form, formsets with HTML array

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Im trying to create a dynamic form that uses a models relationship to generate the formset.

Here is a brief overview of the application. I have a customer table (joined to django admin user table), products table, order table and some join tables. The customer_product table contains a pre built order form that can be edited. I use some join table to create new order_instances that can be referenced from the order table for historical data.

**` Customer has one to one relationship with user table**

```
customer table
--------------
id


product table
-------------
id | product_id
```

**` Customer has and belongs to many products**

```
customer_product (pre-built order templates)
----------------
id | customer_id | product_id
```

**' Customer has and belongs to many products. Customer has many orders**

```
customer_product_order (customer initiated order)
----------------------
id | customer_id | product_id | order_id | quantity

order (main order table. each record contains meta data for that order)
-------
id | invoice_number | delivery_date
```

I don't know how to use formsets in this case, that will let be build dynamic form and save to a customer_product_order table and order table. Currently i have the form outputting but it's checking the customer_product table the second time rather than letting the forms.py oncstruct it. Also couldnt construct the html array in forms.py page.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
import pprint

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "customers"})
    customer_product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='CustomerProduct')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company_name

class CustomerProduct(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.customer.company_name

class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class Order(models.Model):
    customer_product_order = models.ManyToManyField('CustomerProduct', through='CustomerProductOrder')
    purchase_order_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_placing_order = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CustomerProductOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    customer_product = models.ForeignKey('CustomerProduct')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    instructions = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    order_correct = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.customer_product.customer.company_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer Order"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import CustomerProduct

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        products = CustomerProduct.objects.filter(customer_id=1)

        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        counter = 1
        for q in products:
            self.fields['product[quantity][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['product[item][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['product[description][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            counter += 1

    purchase_order_number = forms.CharField(required=True)
    person_placing_order =  forms.CharField(required=True)
    delivery_date_request = forms.DateField(required=True,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    instructions = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100, 'class': 'form-control'}))
    confirm_order = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
```

views.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import CustomerProduct

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        products = CustomerProduct.objects.filter(customer_id=1)

        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        counter = 1
        for q in products:
            self.fields['product[quantity][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['product[item][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['product[description][' + str(q.id) + ']' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            counter += 1

    purchase_order_number = forms.CharField(required=True)
    person_placing_order =  forms.CharField(required=True)
    delivery_date_request = forms.DateField(required=True,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    instructions = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100, 'class': 'form-control'}))
    confirm_order = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block orderform %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="/onlineordering/" method="POST">

        <form class="form-inline">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputName2">Date</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">{{ datenow }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputName2">Customer ID:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">{{ username }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputName2">Address</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                1 Main Street<br />
                                Town<br />
                                State<br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputName2">Purchase Order Number</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">{{ form.purchase_order_number }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputEmail2">Person Placing Order</label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">{{ form.person_placing_order }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5"><label for="exampleInputEmail2">Requested Delivery Date</label></div>
                                <div class="col-md-7">{{ form.delivery_date_request }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="text-right">

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-bordered online-ordering-table">
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="20%">Item</th>
                    <th width="70%">Description</th>
                </tr>

                {% for product in products %}

                <tr>
                    <td><input name="product_quantity"  /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.product.item }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.product.description }}</td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}

            </table>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Special Instructions / Comments</label>
                {{ form.instructions }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        {{ form.confirm_order }} I concede the order above is correct and authorize Company to fulfill this order
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE**

With regards to comments about models. I have detailed the relationships above as best as I can. The design and requirements of the app are as follow. Each customer **hasone** user. A customer order sheet is prebuilt by administrators and store in the customer_product table. Customer **hasand belongstomany** products and customer **hasmanyorders**. When an order is placed by the customer, a new order record is added, and the customer_products_order join table is populated, along with quantities of each product.

*The customer_product table is pre-populated by administrators. The customer_product_order (join) and order table is populated by customers.*

I was using the following join to grab customer information from the order model. I couldn't find any other way to recursively join the customer table from the order model. I may be wrong. Even though this is beyond this question, I really appreciate any comments on my code!

```
models.ManyToManyField('CustomerProduct', through='CustomerProductOrder')
```

Comment: Before going into the details regarding dynamic formsets generation, I am a bit curious about your model classes. Could you please give more details regarding the intention behind each `Model` ?
In particular, your design makes it seem you want to be able to have **different customers** for a **single order**, is that intentional ?

Comment: No, that isn't intentional. My intention is not to have different customer for a single order. Company = customer. When the order is placed, the field for "person placing order" is the employee placing the order on the day.

Comment: In your design, `Order` has **many** `CustomerProduct`s. Since each `CustomerProduct` has a `Customer`, it results that a single `Order` can have several different `Customer`s. Also, because the ManyToMany relation is bidirectional, the same `CustomerProduct` can be part of different `Order`s. All those choices are going against the intuitive design (example, violating the fact that there is a single `Customer` for any given `Order`). I think you should give more details about the intention behind each of your `Model` classes, and your design decisions, in order to receive some answers.

Comment: Hi @AdN i have updated the question with relationships and summary of app design and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion we started in the comments and your updated answer, I am unsure about the purpose of you `customer_product` table ? I will update my answer if I finally get it.

(It would actually seem to me that your `customer_id` field in `customer_product` model is redundant with the `customer_id` field in `customer_product_order`, making the table `customer_product` not actually usefull.)

---

To model a product ordering system, you could perhaps move the `customer_id` at the `order` level (from what I understand of your requirements, there a `Customer` has many orders, but and order has a **single** customer, which the current design fails to implement), giving you:

```
product_order
----------------------
id | product_id(ForeignKey) | order_id(ForeignKey) | quantity

order
-------
id | customer_id(ForeignKey) | invoice_number | delivery_date
```

If this model could suit your need, can you clarify what is the question you are facing ?

---

**EDIT:** I think the data modeling is slightly off, and it is not conveying the right message about what you are trying to achieve (making it complicated to help ;). In particular:

> Customer hasand belongstomany products

Seems it could be a misconception: why would a Customer belong to a product ?
It seems more natural that the `Customer` would have a *many-to-**one*** relationship with `Order` instances. And a `Order` would have a *many-to-**one*** relationship with `Products`, potentially joined through an external table containing the `quantity` field (i.e., your `CustomerProductOrder` table).

That would give you this updated and simplified model:

```
    customer table
    --------------
    id | ...


    product table
    -------------
    id | description | ...


    order
    -------
    id | customer_id(ForeignKey) | person_placing_order | invoice_number | delivery_date


    order_content (~= customer_product_order)
    ----------------------
    id | order_id(ForeignKey)  | customer_id | product_id(ForeignKey) | product_quantity
```

Could you please explain why this more trivial design would not be fit for your purpose ? (Hoping that it will allow us to better understand your requirements)

Comment: The customer_product table is pre-populated by administrators. The customer_product_order (join) and order table is populated by customers.

Comment: @madphp And what is the purpose of this administrators populated table ? Is it just an alternative form of order: either the customer creates the order himself, either the administrators do ?

Comment: Another scenario would be. I made an order with one sheet of products. The admin comes in at a later date and removes a product from customer_product table, but that old product is still referenced in the customer_product_order table. Its main purpose is for historical data.

Comment: the customer_product table is a join table for an administrator to construct a order sheet or invoice.

Comment: @madphp I updated the answer with a proposal for a simplified yet complete modelling of a trivial ordering system. If it does not work for the application you are currently writing, could you please explain why ? My hope is that if you state the defects of this model for your problem, it will make your requirements more explicit : )

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The join table between customer and products is to do with the fact that ahead of time, a customer products are pre-populated. This customer has many products, and those product belong to many customers. The join table is the "order sheet".